# Как прописать несколько Email адресов?

Tags: php, email

Объясните пожалуйста. В коде 2 email адреса, для отправки заказа на почту. Какой из них за что отвечает? И как прописать 2 разных email адреса? Пробовал через запятую, не получается.

```
<?php
$subject = 'Заказ от';
$admin_mail = 'admin@yandex.ru';
$body = '
<html>
<head></head>
<body><p>Информация о заказе:</p></body>
</html>';
$headers   = []; 
$headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'; 
$headers[] = 'From: <admin@yandex.ru>';
$headers[] = 'Bcc: Admin <'.$admin_mail.'>';
$headers[] = 'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();
$send_ok = mail($to, $subject, $body, implode("\r\n", $headers));
exit( json_encode($response) );
```

Comment: `$to` - это куда, там указываете необходимые адреса через запятую с пробелом.

Comment: По новым правилам From должен содержать адрес с отправляемого сервера. Иначе почтовик посчитает письмо спамом и может  заблокировать его доставку.

Answer (score 1):

Назначение полей:

- В поле To: (Куда:, Кому:) записывается адрес получателя сообщения. В
  зависимости от используемого сервера или почтовой клиент-программы
  это поле может называться Message To: или Mail To:
- Поле From: Твой адрес E-mail. Обычно этот адрес автоматически
  записывается и поэтому может отсутствовать на экране.
- В поле Subject: (Тема:) указывается краткая аннотация содержания
  сообщения (не более 20–30 знаков)
- В поле СC: (Копия:) при необходимости записываются адреса
  корреспондентов, которым рассылаются копии сообщений.
- В поле ВСC: (Скрытая копия:) указываются адреса корреспондентов,
  которым копии сообщений рассылаются в тайне от первого адресата.

  mail("john@doe.com , marry@mail.com , frank@domain.com",
  "Test e-mail", "Hi, this is a test message!");

Comment: В поле ВСC вставляю свою почту, но письма нет.?

Comment: @steep Если вы запускаете код, который был приведен Вами выше - то в нем есть ошибки. $to - не заполнено. Есть определенный нюанс этого метода, сообщение будет падать в спам если у вас не настроен DKIM

Comment: Я его сюда не стал писать, думал лишнее. `$to = !empty($userdata['user_mail']) ? $userdata['user_mail'] : $admin_mail;`

Comment: DKIM? Где его настроить?

Comment: @steep Настройка https://help.mail.ru/biz/domain/records/dkim-all, разобрались?

Comment: P.S.: на biz.mail.ru - можно бесплатно хостить свою почту формата name@example.com

Comment: Не понимаю, ставлю разные email в 3 и 13 строки. Приходит только на 13-ю

Comment: Ставлю в 13-ю 2 email и не одного письма не приходит

Comment: @steep Документация с примерами http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php + тема на stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238207/php-mail-bcc-multiple-recipients

Comment: Понял, я не так всё думал. Значит мне в BCC нужно 2 email прописать. как? Так не работает `$headers[] = 'Bcc: Admin <'.$admin_mail.', admin2@yandex.ru>';`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79458/discussion-between-roman-tokarev-and-steep).